# How do I send a string alongside an error code with express?

Tags: node.js, http, express

So when a login fails to validate, I currently respong with res.send(401). However I want to send a snippet of text or html along with the error code.

I tried this:

```
res.write('string');
res.send(401);
```

but threw an error and my server wouldn't start.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're mixing Express methods with the native HTTP methods. Since Express' internally uses the native HTTP modules, you should use one or the other.

```
// Express
res.status(401);
res.send('string');
// or the shortcut method
res.send(401, 'string');

// HTTP
res.writeHead(401);
res.end('string');
```

Comment: express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead

Answer (score 16):

From the examples in [express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send)

```
res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!');
res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit more verbose example, but works even when you try to render a template:

`res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')`

or

`res.status(401).render('/401.html')`

Answer (score 1):

```
res.send(error_code,msg);
```

is deprecated. You should do this instead.

```
res.status(error_code).send(msg);
```

**Update:**
For express v 4.13.4, it will throw error when you do this.

```
res.status(error_code).send(msg);
```

saying you can't set headers after they are sent.